# Grid dots in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How can I generate a multi-resolution dot grid (see image) in pgfplots? The dot grid does not necessarily coincide with the axis ticks.

[image: multi-resolution dot grid]

**edit:** The above plot was created using

```
\addplot[only marks,mark=*] plot table[row sep=crcr,]{ high res. coordinates }
\addplot[only marks,mark=*] plot table[row sep=crcr,]{ low res. coordinates }
```

with huge tables of MATLAB-computed coordinates. What I'm looking for in this question, is a way to algorithmically create the dot grid in pgfplots.

Comment: How did you create this image? Can you post the code?

Comment: How did you compute the coordinates in MATLAB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `tikz`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2.6,-2.6) rectangle (2.6,2.6);
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1,...,2}{
    \draw (\x,-2.4) -- (\x,-2.6)node[below,font=\footnotesize] {\x};
    \draw (\x,2.4) -- (\x,2.6);
    }
    \foreach \y in {-2,-1,...,2}{
    \draw (-2.4,\y) -- (-2.6,\y)node[left,font=\footnotesize] {\y};
    \draw (2.6,\y) -- (2.4,\y);
    }
    \foreach \x in {-2.4,-2.2,...,2.4}{
    \foreach \y in {-2.4,-2.2,...,2.4}{
    \fill[black!30] (\x,\y) circle[radius=0.5pt];
    }}
    \foreach \x in {-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4}{
    \foreach \y in {-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4}{
    \fill[black!80] (\x,\y) circle[radius=0.8pt];
    }}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `pgfplots`.

I took Tarass's answer and added the fots to the back ground so that plots come front.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=-2.6,xmax=2.6,
    ymin=-2.6,ymax=2.6,
    after end axis/.code={%
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \foreach \x in {-2.4,-2.2,...,2.4}{
    \foreach \y in {-2.4,-2.2,...,2.4}{
    \fill[black!30] (axis cs:\x,\y) circle[radius=0.5pt];
    }}
    \foreach \x in {-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4}{
    \foreach \y in {-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4}{
    \fill[black!80] (axis cs:\x,\y) circle[radius=0.8pt];
    }}
    \end{scope}
    },]
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is some what slower than Christian Feuersänger's approach though.

With `\addplot` (still slower)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=-2.6,xmax=2.6,
    ymin=-2.6,ymax=2.6,
    ]
    \foreach \x in {-2.4,-2.2,...,2.4}{
    \foreach \y in {-2.4,-2.2,...,2.4}{
    \addplot[only marks,mark size=0.5pt,black!30] coordinates {(\x,\y)} ;
    }}
    \foreach \x in {-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4}{
    \foreach \y in {-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4}{
    \addplot[only marks,mark size=0.8pt,black!80] coordinates {(\x,\y)} ;
    }}
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to use `pgfplots` axis you can always combine them, `\draw` works inside the `axis` environment as well, perhaps you should then use the `axis cs` to position the dots.

Comment: @hugovdberg I know but, I preferred not to mix up. Hence the manual axis. Thanks for noting.

Comment: You're right, I need pgfplots as I will add more plots to the grid. Unfortunately I can't get your code working in pgfplots (I assume \foreach is to blame here). Can you update your example for a working pgfplots version, please?

Comment: As I undersand, @Bloops wants to use pgfplot and he wants that black dots coincide with axis ticks. But I'm maybe wrong ?

Comment: @Bloops, why foreach should be to blame here ?

Comment: @Tarass, no, the dots do not have to coincide with the ticks. The \foreach syntax does not seem to work inside the axis environment.

Comment: It works fine at the right place.

Comment: @Bloops Answer updated.

Comment: Why don't use (axis cs:\x,\y) to have nice matching axis ticks grid ? "doesn't need to" doesn't mean "does not" ?

Comment: @HarishKumar Morever, Bloops says in one of his comments that "I might not had make my self clear enough: The dots need not match up with the ticks but they need to match up with the coordinate system (for example, there is a black dot at (0,0) and the interval between the dots is also important (it is specified in axis coordinate system units)." ;-)

Comment: On coordinate yes, but not synchronized with. On black point on (0,0) and the others are arbytrary placed, not a multiple of the unit (every unit, or half unit ...). It looks not nice ;-) sse my edit.

Comment: Of course, you're right. What is OP ?

Answer (score 4):

Finally with black dots on the coordinate (essentilly done by Harish Kumar):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=-2.6,xmax=2.6,
    ymin=-2.6,ymax=2.6,
    after end axis/.code={%
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \foreach \x in {-2.6,-2.4,...,2.6}{
    \foreach \y in {-2.6,-2.4,...,2.6}{
    \fill[black!30] (axis cs:\x,\y) circle[radius=0.5pt];
    }}
    \foreach \x in {-2,...,2}{
    \foreach \y in {-2,...,2}{
    \fill[black!80] (axis cs:\x,\y) circle[radius=0.8pt];
    }}\end{scope}
    }]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When using `after end axis`, the dots are drawn in front of any plot that is added to the axis. But I'd like the dots to be placed behind additional plots. And `before end axis` seems to not like `\foreach`.

Comment: Sorry, Too bad ;-)

Comment: +1, I used your answer ;) (you were faster and I was sleeping. It was night for me ). And you were very close. Missed it by a whisker. :)

Comment: I use part of yours first ;-) I thought about layers and background but I didn't know exactly how it works. As night came to me to, it was your turn. Thank's for your lights. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Since you explicitly stated that the dots do not need to match up with the coordinate system, you can simply use a fill `pattern` for the background.

This is the most efficient way to get what you want - it scales to arbitrary sizes without enlarging the resulting pdf. It will also be faster when displaying it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{pattern}
    {\pgfpoint{-0.3mm}{-0.3mm}}%% BB lower left
    {\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}% BB upper right
    {\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}% tile size
{
    \foreach \x in {0,0.3333333,0.66666} {%
        \foreach \y in {0,0.333333,0.6666666} {%
            \def\radius{0.1mm}%
            \ifdim\x pt=0pt
                \ifdim\y pt =0pt
                    \def\radius{0.3mm}%
                \fi
            \fi
            \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{\x cm}{\y cm}}{\radius}%
            \pgfusepath{fill}%
        }%
    }%
    %\pgfpathrectangle\pgfpointorigin{\pgfqpoint{1cm}{1cm}}\pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-2,xmax=2,
    ymin=-2,ymax=2,
    axis background/.style={pattern=pattern},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this is entirely unrelated with `pgfplots`.

Comment: Huh, that is kind of intimidating :-) I might not had make my self clear enough: The dots need not match up with the *ticks* but they need to match up with the *coordinate system* (for example, there is a black dot at (0,0) and the interval between the dots is also important (it is specified in axis coordinate system units).

Comment: A pity :) I had hoped that this kind of pattern might actually be useful after I came up with it for a  use-case around an electronic course...  It is a pity that one cannot easily align `pattern` with the coordinate system, otherwise it would be a relatively powerful solution.